# nesting "group by" and "for (each)" statements in php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database composed of many tables. The first table is about 'texts', with some attributes. Another table is about 'manuscripts' that convey those texts (each text can be conveyed by more than one manuscript). The two tables are linked by a 'conveys' table.

When I do the mysql query, I group the texts by textID. But then, I would like to print all the manuscripts that convey the same text. I guess I should write something like "for each textID, show all manuscriptID", but I don't know how to write the code properly.

I'm at this point:

```
FROM text tx, place pl, print pr, manuscript ms, conveys cv
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY txId
```

(and it works fine. But the problem is below)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['txId']!=0)
    for($i=0; $i.'<'.$row['msId'].'.lenght'; $i++) {echo ($row['msId']) . "<br>";}
```

this code prints out the first msId as many time as the entire number of msId that I have in my database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use a [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html), like this:

```
SELECT
  <...other selects...>
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ms.msId ORDER BY ms.msId ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as msIds
FROM text tx, place pl, print pr, manuscript ms, conveys cv
WHERE <...conditions...>
GROUP BY tx.txId
```

Comment: great, thanks! it works perfecty, it was exactly what I needed :)